# No sound in Kali Linux 2016 2 on VMWare

Tags: kali-linux, audio, vmware

I have Kali Linux installed on VMWare but I do not have any sound.

This is what I get when I run `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 53c1030 PCI-X Fusion-MPT Dual Ultra320 SCSI (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI bridge (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge: VMware PCI Express Root Port (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller
02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371/ES1373 / Creative Labs CT2518 (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB controller: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller
```

I installed `libasound2` and `alsa-utils` and `alsa-oss` and then rebooted, still no sound.

> sudo apt-get install libasound2 alsa-utils alsa-oss

I ran the following command, rebooted and still no sound

> systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio

I ran the following command and rebooted, still no sound

> curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nu11secur1ty/pulseaudio/master/pulseaudio.sh | bash

I installed GNOME ALSA and this is how it looks

[image]

And this is the VM settings of the sound card

[image]

Comment: Does the sound work on the host?  What is the host's OS?

Comment: Yes, the sound works on the host. Windows 10.

Comment: you should select *Connected* and *Connect at power on*.

Comment: @GAD3R I already tried that, it doesn't help and it automatically unchecks after I check the "Connected" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official website](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-34368AB3-5742-40CA-8BBA-134833FE200A.html) you can configure  ALSA sound card on VMware as follows:

> 1. Select the virtual machine and select **VM** > **Settings**.
> 2. On the **Hardware** tab, select **Sound Card**.
> 3. Select **Connected** and **Connect at power on**.
> 4. Select Specify host sound card and select the ALSA sound card.
> 5. If the ALSA sound card does not appear in the list, use the
>      `alsa-utils` package to list the ALSA sound cards on the host system
>      and select Specify host sound card again.
>
>    For example: `aplay -L`
> 6. Click OK to save your changes.

Comment: I don't see ALSA sound card in the dropdown of VM settings. doing `alsa-utils` on Kali returns `bash: alsa-utils: command not found` which is weird because it is already installed.

Comment: And the output of `aplay -l` ?

Comment: This `card 0: AudioPCI [Ensoniq AudioPCI], device 0: ES1371/1 [ES1371 DAC2/ADC]` and this `card 0: AudioPCI [Ensoniq AudioPCI], device 1: ES1371/2 [ES1371 DAC1]`

Comment: install `oss4-base` package then run `dpkg-reconfigure linux-sound-base`

Comment: Installed `oss4-base` but running `dpkg-reconfigure linux-sound-base` returns this `pkg-query: package 'linux-sound-base' is not installed and no information is available` and trying to install `linux-sound-base` returns this `Package linux-sound-base is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However the following packages replace it: oss4-base`

Comment: test the sound from the terminal as user `speaker-test -c 2`

Comment: This is the outcome http://pastebin.com/trx4FEiA but no sound came out from the headphones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50980/discussion-between-halnex-and-gad3r).